# How to append value of forms to the object array

Tags: javascript

i am building a simple application that should embed the submitted forms text fields to the table below. i have already made a addtotable function that displays the library arrays objects to the table when manually added.

now upon clicking submit button, i need the forms text fields to go to the array of objects with the thinking that it will also be displayed because of addtotable function.

```js
function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
  this.name = name
  this.author = author
  this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")
const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", "Read")

let myLibrary = []

function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
  myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1)
addBookToLibrary(book2)
addBookToLibrary(book3)

function addBookToTable() {
  let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')

  myLibrary.forEach(b => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'

    if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Read</button></td>'
    } else if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Not read</button></td>'
    }

    content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn" onclick="toggleDelete(this)">Delete</button></td>'
    tr.innerHTML = content
    tbody.appendChild(tr)
  })
}

addBookToTable()

function toggleDelete(o) {
  let p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="Book">Book</label>
    <input type="text" id="Book">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="Author">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="Status">
      <option value="Read">Read</option>
      <option value="Not read">Not read</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you want really ? after submit the values should be added to the table or what?

Comment: Yes i need it to be added to the table.          
the library array contains book objects that are being displayed because of a addtotable function so i really want the values to go into the array as a new book object so it will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need convert your `addBookToTable()` so it accepts a single book instead of adding all books at once.
Then you need a function that reads values from input fields and add them into a new book.

```js
const elBook = document.getElementById("Book"),
      elAuthor = document.getElementById("Author"),
      elStatus = document.getElementById("Status"),
      elTbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
    this.name = name
    this.author = author
    this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")
const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", "Read")


let myLibrary = []


function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
 myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1, book2, book3)

function submitBook()
{
  if (!elBook.value.trim() || !elAuthor.value.trim())
    return false;

  const newBook = new Book(elBook.value, elAuthor.value, elStatus.value);
  elBook.value = elAuthor.value = "";
  elStatus.value = "Read"
  addBookToLibrary(newBook);
  addBookToTable(newBook);
  return false;
}

myLibrary.forEach(addBookToTable);
function addBookToTable(b){

  let tr = document.createElement('tr')
  let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'

  if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Read'){
    content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Read</button></td>'  
   }
   else if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read'){
     content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Not read</button></td>'
   }

   content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn" onclick="toggleDelete(this)">Delete</button></td>'
  tr.innerHTML = content
  elTbody.appendChild(tr)
}
  
  function toggleDelete(o) {
    let p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
  }
```

```html
<form>
        <div>
            <label for="Book">Book</label>
            <input type="text" id="Book">
        </div>
        
         <div>
            <label for="Author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="Author">
         </div>
    
        <div>
            <label for="status">Status</label>
            <select name="status" id="Status">
                <option value="Read">Read</option>
                <option value="Not read">Not read</option>
            </select>
            
        </div>

       <br>
       
        <div> 
            <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick="return submitBook()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>      </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let add=document.getElementById("add")
    let submit=()=>{
        let book=document.getElementById("Book").value
        let author=document.getElementById("Author").value
        let select=document.getElementById("Status").value
        let values=[book,author,select]
        let tr=document.createElement("tr")
        for(let i of values){
            let td=document.createElement("td")
            td.textContent=i
            tr.appendChild(td)
            add.appendChild(tr)
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="Book">Book</label>
    <input type="text" id="Book">
</div>

 <div>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="Author">
 </div>

<div>
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="Status">
        <option value="Read">Read</option>
        <option value="Not read">Not read</option>
    </select>
    
</div>

<br>

<div> 
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>      </td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="add">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When there's a `<button>` without a `type` attribute, or a `<button type="submit">` or an `<input type="submit">` with a `type="submit"` inside a `<form>`, it will by default submit the `<form>` whenever it's clicked. So every time the submit button is clicked the whole page goes black.

Form fields have a `.value` property that needs to be accessed in order to get the values. See **Figure I** and **Figure II**

**Figure I**

```html
<form id="catalog">
  <input id="title" value="Catcher in the Rye">
  <input id="author" value="J.D. Salinger">
  <select id="status">
    <option disabled>Did you read this book?</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Read</option>
    <option value="0">Not Read</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**Figure II**

```js
// Reference <form>
const catalog = document.forms.catalog;

// Reference all form fields in <form>
const fields = catalog.elements;

// Reference individual fields by id or name
const title = fields.title;
const author = fields.author;
const status = fields.status;

// Get values
title.value  // "Catcher in the Rye"
author.value // "J.D. Salinger"
Boolean(status.value) /* Originally a "1", Boolean() converts it to true
                         If value is a "", Boolean() converts it to false */
```

**IMPORTANT:** All values from any element will be a string. If you need to calculate anything make sure that the string is converted into a number. See **Figure III**

**Figure III**

| String | Number | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` "0", '01', and ​​`​1`​​​​ ``` | ``` 10 ``` | ``` 1 (true) 0 (false) ``` |

In the example, each `<tr>` is given a `data-*` attribute with a value that corresponds with the index position it has within `<tbody>`. The attribute is `data-idx` and the value is used to trace where the `<tr>`'s counterpart is in the `library` array so the object can be removed along with the `<tr>`.

**View example in Full Page Mode**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <style>
  html {
    font: 300 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI"
  }
  
  body {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  form {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  fieldset {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    width: max-content;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }

  legend {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }

  label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  label+label {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
  }

  label b {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 300
  }

  input,
  select,
  button {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
  }

  [type="text"] {
    min-width: 32vw;
  }
  
  select {
    height: 2rem;
  }
    
  button {
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 96vw;
  }

  th {
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  th:first-of-type,
  th:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 24vw;
  }

  th:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 14vw;
  }

  th:last-of-type {
    width: 11vw;
  }

  td {
    padding: 0.25rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px groove grey;
  }

  td button {
    margin-top: -0.05rem;
  }

  td label b {
    width: max-content;
  }

  .status {
    margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
  }

  b.read::before {
    content: " Not Read";
  }

  .status:checked+b.read::before {
    content: " Read";
  }

  .as-console-row::after {
    width: 0;
    font-size: 0;
  }

  .as-console-row-code {
    word-break: break-word;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="catalog">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Library Catalog</legend>
      <label><b>Title:</b><input id="title" type="text" required></label>
      <label><b>Author:</b><input id="author" type="text" required></label>
      <label for="status"><b>Status:</b>
        <select id="status" required>
          <option selected disabled>Have you read this book?</option>
          <option value="1">Read</option>
          <option value="">Not read</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <button>Add Book</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
  const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", true);
  const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin");
  const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", true);
  let library = addData(book1, book2, book3);
  addBooks(library);

  function Book(title, author, status = false) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.status = status;
  }

  function addData(...books) {
    return [...books];
  }

  function addBooks(array) {
    const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    const offset = tbody.rows.length;
    let result = array.flatMap((b, i) => {
      const html = `
      <tr data-idx="${offset + i}">
        <td>
          <output name="title" class="title data">${b.title}</output>
        </td>
        <td>
          <output name="author" class="author data">${b.author}</output>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>
            <input name="status" class="status data" 
             type="checkbox" value="${b.status}">
            <b class="read"></b>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>`;
      tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
      if (+b.status) {
        tbody.rows[offset + i].querySelector(".status").checked = true;
      }
      return b;
    });
    console.log("=========|Data to Table|=========");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }

  const catalog = document.forms.catalog;
  catalog.onsubmit = addFields;

  function addFields(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = this.elements;
    const book = [new Book(
      fields.title.value, 
      fields.author.value, 
      Boolean(fields.status.value)
    )];
    library.push(book[0]);
    addBooks(book);
    this.reset();
    console.log("=========|Library Data|=========");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(library));
  }

  document.querySelector('tbody').onclick = function(event) {
    const clicked = event.target;
    let idx;
    if (clicked !== this && clicked.matches(".remove")) {
      let row = clicked.closest('tr');
      idx = +row.dataset.idx;
      row.remove();
    }
    library.splice(idx, 1);
    console.log("========| Library Data  |========");     
    console.log("========| One Item Less |========");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(library));
  };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```